# Cannot escape char in autohotkeys

Tags: autohotkey

I want to replace `funcarg` with `function(){console.log(arguments)}`
It never work it always replace `funcarg` with `function()`

This is my code:

```
::funcarg::function(){console.log(arguments)}
```

I read this, and try many different ways

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm

```
::funcarg::function()\{console.log(arguments)}
::funcarg::function()%{console.log(arguments)}
::funcarg::function()'{console.log(arguments)}
::funcarg::function()`{console.log(arguments)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple alternatives to @Schneyer's method.

HotString Raw Mode:

```
:R:funcarg::function(){console.log(arguments)}
```

Using SendInput and Raw Mode:

```
::funcarg::
var := "function(){console.log(arguments)}"
SendInput % "{Raw}" var
return
```

Clipboard / Send method:

```
::funcarg::
clipboard := "function(){console.log(arguments)}"
sendInput, {ctrl down}{v}{ctrl up}
return
```

Comment: I like the `HotString Raw Mode`. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Wrap them in curly brackets `{{}` and `{}}`

```
::funcarg::function(){{}console.log(arguments){}}
```

A hotstring gets replaced with a hotkey + send command by AHK, with the curly brackets you mark it as special keys to be send.